# I want to make the height of this section increase with its content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried this

```
<section class="unique">
    <div class="this d-flex pt-5">
        <div class="leftside2 w-50 h-100">
            <img src="images/twowomen.jpg" alt="twowomen" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="rightside2 w-50 h-100">
            <h5 class="text-success pl-5">WE HELP YOU</h5>
            <div class="fineText d-flex pl-5">
                <h3>Get A</h3>
                <h3 class="consulting pl-2">CONSULTING</h3>
            </div>
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs font-weight-bold py-2 ml-5" placeholder="Your Name" id="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs font-weight-bold py-2 ml-5" placeholder="Your Email Adress" id="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs font-weight-bold py-2 ml-5" placeholder="Phone Number" id="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs font-weight-bold py-2 ml-5" placeholder="I would like to discuss" id="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ml-5">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info bg-success w-25 text-white font-weight-bold p-4">
        <span>ADDRESS</span>
        <p class="pb-3">Mostafa Naguib <br> Street, 14 Box, Cairo, <br> Egypt</p>
        <span>EMAIL</span>
        <p class="pb-3">cairooffice@financer.com</p>
        <span>PHONE NUMBER</span>
        <p class="pb-3"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">002 0100 843 1112</a></p>
        <span>WEBSITE</span>
        <p>www.financer.org</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then the style:

```
.form-group .inputs{
border: none !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc !important;
width: 70% !important;
}
.form-group .btn{
padding: 15px !important;
padding-left: 45px !important;
padding-right: 45px !important;
border-radius: 50px !important;
}
.fineText .consulting{
font-size: 37px;
font-family: "Gabriola";
color: #28a745;
font-weight: bolder;
}
.rightside2{
padding-left: 100px !important;
}
.info{
position: absolute;
top: 1630px;
left: 400px;
/* padding: 35px !important; */
}

.unique{
height: 600px;
}
.this .rightside2 .leftside2{
height: 100%;
}
```

But after trying it only the section's height increases but the `leftside and` rightside`
remains the same.

See this image: [image]

The space above and below the image is the height of the section and those `leftside` and `rightside` is supposed to fill the space.

I've made research i didn't find any helpful suggestion.

Please I need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the fixed height? `height: 600px;`

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure the fixed height is the problem because that fixed height is for the section

Comment: @Paulie_D I've tried it though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed measurements, why don't you try using percentages? I am also not clear on what you mean by

> The space above and below the image is the height of the section and those leftside and rightside is supposed to fill the space.

Could you expand on that and maybe I can help further?

Comment: The two divs are in that section and that space above them and below them is the space that the section has because of its height

Comment: I also want it to be to have reasonable height and width so that it will not be blurry